# preg_match dumps empty array

Tags: php, regex

Given that I have url `https://website.com/test/demo/success.php?token=-abc123-` I want to get value `abc123`. Somehow I get two empty strings on my `preg_match`.

```
$url = 'https://website.com/test/demo/success.php?token=-abc123-';
preg_match('-(.*?)-', $url, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

Output: `array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" }`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If there's no items in the result array, then the error is in your RegEx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use regex delimiter:

```
preg_match('/-(.*?)-/', $url, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

OR better:

```
preg_match('/-([^-]*)-/', $url, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: Thanks, I guess initially some folks though that `-` itself is delimiter and am I adding one more on top of it.

Comment: Yeah you are right. The first solution which you initially gave was perfect. People sometimes gets frustrated when they see `1 new answer has been posted` while they were typing one :P